# How to make Bean Validation 1.0 work with JBoss AS 5.1?

Tags: jboss, classloader, jboss5.x, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a problem with using Bean Validation 1.0 in JBoss AS 5.1.0.

When I use Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final, the following exception occurs when I try to validate an object :

> NoSuchMethodError... when trying to call org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Class type, String category)

The problem is that :

### - Dependency tree for hibernate-validator 4.3 contains :

```
+- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.3.0.Final:compile
|  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
|  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.CR2:compile
```

### - Dependency tree for jboss-as-server 5.1 contains :

```
+- org.jboss.jbossas:jboss-as-server:5.1.0.GA
|  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-spi:2.1.0.GA
|  +- etc...
```

And the old **Logger** class in jboss-logging-spi 2.1 (located in JBOSS_HOME/lib) doesn't contain this method.

### My question is :

*How to force my application deployed in JBoss to use the newer jboss-logging library ?*

### My current workaround :

For the moment, the workaround I found is to use hibernate-validator 4.1.0.Final which doesn't use **jboss-logging** but **slf4j-api** instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure class loading specifics in JBoss AS 5.x by adding a file named `jboss-classloading.xml` to `WEB-INF` (when deploying a WAR) or `META-INF` (when deploying an EAR). In case of a WAR, the following should do the trick:

```
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
    domain="YourAppNameDomain"
    parent-domain="Ignored"
    export-all="NON_EMPTY"
    import-all="true">
</classloading>
```

You can find some more information on the available options [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-configuration/solving-jboss-5-classloading-issues), [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jboss-microcontainer-classloading) and [here](http://phytodata.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/demystifying-the-jboss5-jboss-classloading-xml-file/).

Comment: I was first thinking of using java2ParentDelegation in jboss-web.xml, but didn't succeed. I'll try your solution.

Comment: Congrats to getting over 2000 ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Adding `hibernate-validator` after `hibernate-core` in the pom order fixed a similar problem to me.